# Bundling files in "src" folder into "public" folder using webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, webpack

How to Bundle all the files inside “src” folder and replace the existing bundled files inside “Public” folder  in any Node.js web app?

My project structure is similar to this: https://github.com/googlearchive/friendlypix-web

Answer (score 1):

For javascript files, you should have at least one entry-point for your application in order to bundle it.

Example of `webpack.config.json` with one entrypoint `src/index.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  },
};
```

More information about bundling one or many entry-points : https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/

Furthermore, if you have imported static assets (images, css, saas, fonts...) in your javascript files, you need to add some configuration and eventually install webpack loaders to bundle them.

For example, for CSS assets :

- Install webpack loaders via `npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader`
- Update webpack configuration

  ```
   const path = require('path');

   module.exports = {
     entry: './src/index.js',
     output: {
       filename: 'bundle.js',
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
     },
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.css$/i,
           use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
         },
       ],
     },
   };
  ```

More information about asset management : https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/

Finally, you may need to bundle static files or directories that are not imported in your javascript files and you want to copy them as they are.

In this case, you could use the `copy-webpack-plugin` :

- Install plugin via `npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev`
- Update webpack configuration

  ```
   const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

   module.exports = {
     ...
     plugins: [
       new CopyPlugin({
         patterns: [
           { from: "source", to: "dest" },
           { from: "other", to: "public" },
         ],
       }),
     ],
     ...
   }
  ```

More info about `copy-webpack-plugin` : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/

I really recommend you to take a look at the official webpack documentation which covers topics including creating production bundles, code splitting, caching and other tips and hints.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But my project structure is different from what you've suggested. I added a reference in my question.